# iOS: View heights not adding up

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am trying to implement a custom browser with UIWebView in my app. The XIB file has an address bar at the top of height 35px and a navigation bar at the bottom of height 35px. So, I am dynamically adding the webView in viewDidLoad(). This is how I am setting the frame of webview,

```
webView.frame=CGRectMake(0, top.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-(top.frame.size.height+bottom.frame.size.height));
```

I assumed this would do the trick and the webview will fix exactly in between the address and the navigation bars. However, on running on the device or the simulator, the webview is easily covering up the navigation bar. These are the respective heights of the views in the controller.

self.view.bounds.size.height = 548.000000, top.view.bounds.size.height = 35, bottom.view.bounds.size.height = 35.

I am not sure whats the problem is. Can someone please let me know?

Comment: have you tried putting this line in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: Thanks, That did the job. Can you let me know why the value self.view.bounds.size.height is different in viewDidLoad() and viewDidLayoutSubviews()? In the first case the height was 548 and in the other case the height was 460.

Comment: The layout of the views is not complete in `viewDidLoad` so the dimensions are not accurate/reliable until later in the view controller lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hard code frame sizes. Get the target size from the superview's view:

```
`webView.frame = self.view.bounds;`
```

and make sure your web view has an autoresizingMask set to:

```
`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`.
```